# activating a Function from another function in a different class

Tags: python, class, program-entry-point, function

I am trying to activate a function that will, once i'm finished, change the control variables for some motors. the commands are coming in over wifi via socket server. Here is the code;

```
import SocketServer
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
      def handle(self):
            self.DriveSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            self.SteeringSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            #print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
            #print(self.DriveSend)
            #print(self.SteeringSend)
            #self.request.sendall(self.DriveSend.upper())
            #self.request.sendall(self.SteeringSend.upper())
            return (self.DriveSend,self.SteeringSend)
            MotorControl()

def MotorControl():
      MotorVar = MyTCPHandler()
      MotorVar.handle()
      MotorVar.DriveSend
      MotorVar.SteeringSend
      print(MotorVar.DriveSend)
      print(MotorVar.SteeringSend)
      print('test')

if __name__ == "__main__":
      HOST, PORT = "192.168.2.12", 9999
      server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
      server.serve_forever()
```

As you can see the server runs constantly and looks out for incoming messages, i would like it to run the function MotorControl every time it receives a new message ideally from my client program. I tried this but it doesn't print any values (my way of testing it with something basic before i try and control anything) all the commented out sections are bits of code from the original testing to check the server side of things. all of which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here. Firstly, the MyTCPHandler method returns before calling the function. When a return in a function is hit, execution returns immediately and no more code in that function will be executed.

Secondly, you've got the MyTCPHandler method calling the MotorControl function, but then the function instantiates a new instance of the class, which naturally doesn't have any of the information set. Instead, you should pass your instance to the function.

So:

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
      def handle(self):
            self.DriveSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            self.SteeringSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            MotorControl(self)
            return (self.DriveSend,self.SteeringSend)

def MotorControl(motor_var):
      print(motor_var.DriveSend)
      print(motor_var.SteeringSend)
      print('test')
```

Although on reflection, it's not clear why you want this in a standalone function anyway. You should perhaps make MotorControl a method on MyTCPHandler, then it will already have access to `self`.

Comment: Thankyou very much! been struggling with this for a while. With regards to wanting a independent function this is due to my future aims which involve trying to build in the option for autonomous control :P (ambitious for my level of programming i know) and will simply be using the motorcontrol function to controll the motors from whatever input is active at the time. so i wanted it seperate